# Converting similarity matrix before inputting to t-sne

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, tsne

I have a cosine similarity matrix where I want to adjust it to inputto t-sne. I fond the following explanation in a FAQ. As mentioned there I have made the diagonals to zero. what does it mean by `symmetrize the pairwise similarity matrix, and normalize it to sum up to one`?

> Can I use a pairwise similarity matrix as input into t-SNE?
>
> Yes you can! For instance, we successfully applied t-SNE on a dataset
>   of word association data. Download the Matlab implementation, make
>   sure the diagonal of the pairwise similarity matrix contains only
>   zeros, symmetrize the pairwise similarity matrix, and normalize it to
>   sum up to one. You can now use the result as input into the tsne_p.m
>   function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scale the values by some constant factor so the sum of every entry in the matrix results in 1.0.

You can achieve this by using `mat /= mat.sum()`, where `mat` is your matrix.